# Do you know why i got different statistics from FB pixel and google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook

Do you know why I got different statistics from FB pixel and google analytics?

In facebook pixel, I have 53 link clicks and in Google analytics just 49.

In final I don't care. I just want to know why is the difference.

Comment: Those numbers are close enough to be considered equal in this kind of context

Comment: See also: [Big difference between Google Analytics and Piwik](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76340/big-difference-between-google-analytics-and-piwik) and [Huge difference in visits/hits between IIS logs and google analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/huge-difference-in-visits-hits-between-iis-logs-and-google-analytics)

Comment: [What can I do about the difference between adsense and analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82846/what-can-i-do-about-the-difference-between-adsense-and-analytics) and [Google Search Console vs. Google Analytics Data Difference](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86032/google-search-console-vs-google-analytics-data-difference) -- It is very rare for two ways of measuring traffic to come out exactly equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons why Facebook and Google Analytics register different data but the most important is that Facebook is based on **clicks** and Analytics on **sessions**.

If you are not using the same metric, data can't be the same.

Chech [Facebook's official documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/147965221941551) in order to minimize the gap between both apps.